Last scene: a man is killed in his own dream and men in suits look over him
In which movie is a man killed in his own dream and men in suits look over him? Also his friend is a dentist who starts to believe that the main character is involved in a conspiracy and then the dentist is killed in one of the dreams. But in the real world the deaths appear as accidents.
This was either a TV movie or episode in a show from the seventies or eighties, The main character is a doctor or reporter type role, but the key part is the deaths are accidents in the real world. But in his dreams he knows they are assassinations.

Sounds like a twilight zone premise...

Hadn't thought of that will check IMDB for Episode guide, definitely not outer limits too early for the original series and too late for the reamke.  Please stand by...

This is a bit of a stretch, but could it be Terry Gilliam's "Brazil"?  The friend is a torturer, not a dentist, but his victims are strapped into what looks like a dentist's chair.  The men in suits look over Sam Lowry at 1:30 in this clip: (Sorry it's in French)  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlHe-hYMkqk

Reminds me of 1985's "Brazil" directed by Terry Gilliam.
In final scene, the main character is tortured in a clinical setting by his former friend, who is wearing outfit similar to dentist. The friend accuses the main character of being disloyal to the government. While being tortured, the main character loses his mind and retreats into fantasy, as the friend and another torturer look him over, saying "I think we lost him."



Deadly Dream (1971)
From TCM, here's a synopsis:

A research scientist is driven to the brink by a recurring dream that
  he is marked for death by a mysterious tribunal, and soon he is unable
  to separate his dreams from reality -- and vice versa.

From Great Old Movies, the plot in detail:

Dr. Jim Hanley is working on certain revolutionary DNA experiments
  that have the powers-that-be at his university nervous. He begins to
  have recurring dreams in which he is chased by menacing members of a
  group calling themselves the Tribunal. 
The spooky thing is that when he wakes up he has the minor injuries
  that he received running from the group in his nightmares. 
Then he starts seeing some of these men in his waking hours, also
  bearing scars from the dreams.
A colleague tries to help him in one of his nightmares, but he is
  later killed in real life. 
Before long, Hanley is totally paranoid, suspecting anyone and
  everyone of plotting against him, including his own wife. He begins to
  wonder if his "real" life is just a dream, and the world of his
  nightmare is his true reality.

It was first broadcast as part of ABC's Movie of the Week series. Here are the closing scenes where the members of the Tribunal gather around Hanley:



Most of it appears to fit your description. Watch the movie here to confirm.

It sounds like the movie Dreamscape. With Max Von Sydow, it's from 1984 and matches much of your criteria - but not all of it. In this movie, Max Von Sydow's not a dentist, but a sleep disorder specialist...

Hi Ben definitely not Dreamscape, i am 100% sure on the main leads' friends profession.  The key part to the piece is the chilling final scene with these men standing over the main character in his own dream, which he has died in.  Maybe I'll never know.  However, to say thanks if you've never seen LOOKER from early eighties good (slightly cheesy) thriller with a young Albert Finney prooving he doesn't have to sing to Bob Cratchet & Tiny Tim or do an unconvincing Belgian accent to do a fairly good movie.  cheers.
